# Constant network timeouts since few weeks on fresh Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

Since few weeks I  have constant network timeouts. Here are logs from `NetworkManager`:

```
gru 12 11:37:24 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544611044.3534] connectivity: (wlp3s0) timed out
gru 12 11:37:24 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544611044.3536] connectivity: (enx803f5d098ae6) timed out
gru 12 11:37:24 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544611044.3537] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
gru 12 11:41:58 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544611318.4725] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
gru 12 12:12:24 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544613144.3487] connectivity: (wlp3s0) timed out
gru 12 12:12:24 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544613144.3495] connectivity: (enx803f5d098ae6) timed out
gru 12 12:12:24 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544613144.3495] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
gru 12 12:16:57 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544613417.1304] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
gru 12 12:16:57 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544613417.1313] policy: set 'xxx 1' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
gru 12 12:17:24 r2d2l NetworkManager[975]: <info>  [1544613444.3464] connectivity: (enx803f5d098ae6) timed out
```

My device is Xiaomi Notebook 15 Pro with USB C hub. It first started on my old Ubuntu 18.04 installation. Since then I have tried USB 3.0 HUB, USB 3.0 active (powered) HUB, new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 and so on. On Windows everything is OK so I am pretty sure it's a software problem. I have also updated the Kernel but it did not help.

Could you please help me debug this? What can I do to fix it?